# Android IOException is null, Throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, exception, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I'm working on an application for *Android* and I'm having an `AsyncTask` connect to a server through a client socket in the `doInBackground` method.

All variables that are being used have been set and I have checked in real time that they are valid before being used. The weird thing is that after trying to create the socket with the designated host/port, it immediately throws an `IOException`, which in itself is not a problem :P but the value `ex` is `null`. I have never seen anything like this and I found some similar cases on google, but none of them yielded a solution.

The code that is throwing the exception,as well as the `catch` block:

```
@Override
protected Socket doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Socket sock = null;

    try {
        sock = new Socket("10.0.0.86", 44444);
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sock;
}
```

The rest of the code is nothing of help, it's just some getter/setters. Here's the log from the android device:

> 07-28 03:30:23.438
>   9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication I/System.out﹕
>   Sending WAIT chunk 07-28 03:30:23.438
>   9514-9520/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication I/dalvikvm﹕
>   Debugger is active 07-28 03:30:23.438
>   9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication
>   W/ActivityThread﹕ Application
>   com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication is waiting for the
>   debugger on port 8100... 07-28 03:30:23.638
>   9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication I/System.out﹕
>   Debugger has connected 07-28 03:30:23.638
>   9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication I/System.out﹕
>   waiting for debugger to settle... 07-28 03:30:23.838
>   9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication I/System.out﹕
>   waiting for debugger to settle... 07-28 03:30:24.038
>   9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication I/System.out﹕
>   waiting for debugger to settle... 07-28 03:30:24.238
>   9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication I/System.out﹕
>   waiting for debugger to settle... 07-28 03:30:24.438
>   9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication I/System.out﹕
>   waiting for debugger to settle... 07-28 03:30:24.638
>   9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication I/System.out﹕
>   waiting for debugger to settle... 07-28 03:30:24.838
>   9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication I/System.out﹕
>   waiting for debugger to settle... 07-28 03:30:25.038
>   9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication I/System.out﹕
>   debugger has settled (1482) 07-28 03:30:25.238
>   9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication I/Adreno-EGL﹕
>   : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
>       OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.06
>       Build Date: 02/12/14 Wed
>       Local Branch: au090
>       Remote Branch:
>       Local Patches:
>       Reconstruct Branch: 07-28 03:30:25.268    9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication
>   D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0 07-28 03:30:25.308
>   9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication
>   D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x502 07-28
>   03:30:25.308    9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication
>   E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ GL_INVALID_OPERATION 07-28 03:30:25.318
>   9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication
>   I/ActivityManager﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id:
>   android.os.BinderProxy@43682588 time:268397923 07-28 03:30:26.468
>   9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication
>   I/ActivityManager﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id:
>   android.os.BinderProxy@43682588 time:268399075 07-28 03:30:29.908
>   9514-9514/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication
>   I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 150 frames!  The application may be doing too
>   much work on its main thread. 07-28 03:30:33.538
>   9514-9913/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication W/dalvikvm﹕
>   threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e98d88)
>   07-28 03:30:33.578
>   9514-9913/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
>       Process: com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication, PID: 9514
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication.Networking.doInBackground(Networking.java:51)
>               at com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication.Networking.doInBackground(Networking.java:12)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 07-28 03:35:33.628    9514-9913/com.TestApplication.VEStudio.TestApplication
>   I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 9514 SIG: 9

Any help at all with this issue would be greatly appreciated, and hopefully someone in the future will need the same intel.

Comment: There are numerous reports of this problem here. It seems to indicate a ***major*** bug in Android.

Comment: yes it seems like it to me aswell, and its giving me a hard time debugging my application, whoever is in charge of the development of android should look into this.

Comment: You might want to report the bug here: https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html (there's a link on that page that lets you search to see if anyone else has reported a similar issue, also).

Comment: Your ex is null because it is a null pointer exception.. Have u tried this code in debugging mode??

Comment: ex should not be null as it is not a catch for null pointer exceptions, in fact the null value in ex is what is causing the null pointer exception crash :P